# git clone asking for password (multiple users)

Tags: git, ssh

I have setup a VM with multiple users. My primary users is VM-User and using that account I created another user called "Joe". I have cloned a git repo by loggin into the VM-User and everything works fine.

The problem I'm having is when I try to clone the same repo by loggin into the user "Joe" it asks me for a password for the git server.

```
git clone git@0.0.0.0:repo.git some_folder
```

its shows:

```
git@0.0.0.0's password: (asks me to type in a password)
```

I have created an ssh key for "Joe" and added it to gitosis.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance :)

SSH Debug Log:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: email@example.com
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/joe/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/joe/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/joe/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Comment: What happens if you try connect via SSH without Git (just `ssh git@0.0.0.0`)? Use `ssh -v git@0.0.0.0` to see if your SSH key is used for connecting.

Comment: Same thing. It asks me for the password.

Comment: Try using `ssh -v git@0.0.0.0` (mind the `-v` flag). It should give more information on why the SSH authentication fails (especially look for lines like "Offering RSA public key: /home/user/.ssh/my_key").

Comment: I found something interesting. Look at question. Do you know what that means? Im new to git.

Comment: @FarhanAhmad: it's got nothing to do with git. Do you actually have the right authorized keys on the target machine?

Comment: Are you sure you pushed your gitosis-admin to the server in addition to commiting it?

Comment: Yes, I have added that key in the gitosis-admin. Just for testing, I have tried to clone it on another computer and it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have an authorized key set up on the cloning machine, otherwise SSH would never get to this step:

```
 debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

I would check that I have the correct key(s) on the VM and the cloning machine.

Comment: It sounds like this is the issue. Would generating the key for multiple users cause this type of behaviour? Is there a special way to generate the ssh key on a computer with multiple users? Im assuming each user would have to generate their own ssh key? (which is what I'm doing)

Comment: No, you just need to generate the key for each user, then add each user's key to the server in their account's `.ssh/known_hosts` file.

Comment: I figured it out. For some reason each users .ssh directory was owned by the root user. By simply deleting the .ssh directory and creating it as the logged in user, fixed it. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I just pressed Enter in response to `Enter file in which to save the key (/c/Users/sposada/.ssh/id_rsa):` and I copied the `id_rsa.pub` and changed the name in the server.

git is trying to get the ssh public key from `/home/joe/.ssh/id_rsa` but you have `/home/joe/.ssh/joe`